# How can I change the attribute in header section of cshtml files?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem about removing attributes when I navigate pages.

I used PartialView in HomeController to define `index.cshtml` page.

The line which I pass the data to the destination is showed orderly.

```
HomeController -> Contract.cshtml -> _Layout.cshtml -> NavbarPartial.cshtml
```

Here is `HomeController.cs` file shown below.

```
public ActionResult ContractUs()
        {
            ViewBag.Attribute = ""; // header-transparent
            return View();
        }
```

Here is my `Contract.cshtml` shown below.

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Contract Us";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

Here is my `_Layout.cshtml` shown below.

```
Html.RenderAction("NavbarPartial", "Home");
```

Here is my `NavbarPartial.cshtml` shown below.

```
<header id="header" class="fixed-top d-flex align-items-center header-transparent">
</header>
```

What I want to do is to show this header code snippet in the index page and show another one on another page like this shown as below without changing NavbarPartial.cshtml.

Index.cshtml

```
<header id="header" class="fixed-top d-flex align-items-center header-transparent">
</header>
```

Contract.cshtml

```
<header id="header" class="fixed-top d-flex align-items-center">
</header>
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you render your partial view from another view, then you can send some parameters to decide what class should be applied. So let's look at the example.

We call partial view and send additional data:

```
@{Html.RenderPartial("_Header", new ViewDataDictionary { { "ApplyStyle", true } });}
```

and then in partial view we can apply style conditionally:

```
@{
    var yourClasses = "";
    if ((bool)ViewData["ApplyStyle"])
    {
        yourClasses = "fixed-top d-flex align-items-center header-transparent";
    }
    else
    {
        yourClasses = "fixed-top d-flex align-items-center";
    }

}

<header id="header" class="@yourClasses">
    This is header!
</header>
```

**UPDATE:**

This is [a fiddle with complete example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nJeuHm). However, this fiddle does not support `PartialView`, but I believe basic idea is shown.

Comment: I got an error in if(@ViewData["ApplyStyle"]). Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'bool'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?). How can I fix it?

Comment: I got an error in if((bool)@ViewData["ApplyStyle"]) again. How can I fix it?

Comment: @TonyBrand please, see my updated answer. I've created a project, tested and it works. Thanks!

Comment: I still got an error in if((bool)@ViewData["ApplyStyle"]) again after I run the program. How can I fix it?

Comment: @TonyBrand you should write `if ((bool)ViewData["ApplyStyle"])`, not with `if(@ViewData["ApplyStyle"])`

Comment: When I wrote if ((bool)ViewData["ApplyStyle"]), I got a System error. That's why I couldn't fix it.

Comment: @TonyBrand could you send the message of the error?

Comment: NullReferenceException

Comment: I already applied your code but it didn't work flawlessly.

Comment: @TonyBrand I've created a [fiddle with complete example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nJeuHm). However, this fiddle does not support `PartialView`, but I believe basic idea is shown

Comment: I'll look it through.

Comment: @TonyBrand sorry, I've worked with JQuery very little

Answer (score -1):

Try using conditions in class value.

For example:

```html
<header id="header" class="fixed-top d-flex align-items-center @(@Model.name === 'index' ? 'header-transparent' : '')">
```

If you dont have any kind of variable name for current component, you can use Javascript's **location** object.
**window.location.pathname** will provide you the pathname of current page.
Using this value you can add conditional class values

Comment: I did what you said but I got an error. Its message is Too Many characters in character literal.

Comment: Try this

<header id="header" class="fixed-top d-flex align-items-center @(@Model.name === "index" ? "header-transparent" : "")">

Comment: Index is a page not a model. That's why I got this kind of error. Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool'  and Invalid expression term '='